# How can I smooth the line between 2 points in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawing

I already know how to draw a line between 2 points, but the line seems not so smooth. What can I do to make it smoother? Thanks you.

```
- (void)drawLineFrom:(CGPoint)start To:(CGPoint)end {
// begin image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageLineView.frame.size);

// define image rect for drawing
[self.imageLineView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageLineView.frame.size.width, imageLineView.frame.size.height)];

// set line properties
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0f);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0f, .0f, .0f, 1.0);

// move context to start point
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), start.x, start.y);

// define path to end point
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), end.x, end.y);

// stroke path
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

// flush context to be sure all drawing operations were processed
CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

// get UIImage from context and pass it to our image view
imageLineView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// end image context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not smooth"? You have two points, you're going to get a straight line between them. What is smooth about that?

Comment: try this http://tonyngo.net/2011/09/smooth-line-drawing-in-ios/

Comment: @Abizern: the line is a bit of jaggy.

Comment: @QuangLuu That is an unacceptable description.  Post a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: I have added the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw smooth line using Bezier Path.

You can have some more information here.
[Bézier Paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Anti-Aliasing. you'll need to set the UIViewEdgeAntialiasing key to YES in your Info.plist.